# Utils in Catalyst (Perl)

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, catalyst

Where should I place functions like, for example, `sum_it_all()` in Catalyst project?

It's not a model, that's nothing about data, it's not a controller because it doesn't ask the web-request. It's just a simple function and I want it to be accessible in all my controllers.

Now I use Model/Utils.pm and `$c->model("utils")->sum_it_all()`, but it seems to be really ridiculous.

Comment: I don't know Catalyst, so this may not be any help, but in symfony, there is a top-level lib which contains lib/models and lib/forms, so I just put this sort of thing in lib directly.

Comment: When I first met Catalyst, I did exactly what you did (creating a Model). Models are very lightweight in Catalyst, so it's not a totally broken idea. However, it does make much more sense to just create a module outside of the catalyst namespace, as Sid Burn wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need this functions in a Catalyst Controller, just embed it in the controller where you need it. If you need the same function in several Controller. Create a new Module that contains all your functions. If your Project is named "Foo", then create for example "Foo::Helpers".

In every controller where you need some functions from your helper just import them "use Foo::Helper qw(sum)"

Look at [Sub::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub%3a%3aExporter) for exporting functions.

Comment: If I did this, what folder should the module be in?

Comment: From your main project root. Place the modul in `lib/Foo/Helpers.pm`

Comment: Thanks @Sid So then I should add a `use Foo::Helpers;" on the top and use it like a perl package right? (As opposed to a `$c->models("Foo"..` )

Comment: The file you created is just a normal Perl Module and starts with `package Foo::Helpers` and so on. Other Catalyst Controllers or other Modules in your project then can just include the module with `use Foo::Helpers qw(sum)`. If you want to import a function you need to setup "Exporting" in Foo::Helpers. Use Sub::Exporter for this.

Answer (score 3):

If it's nothing Catalyst specific, just use it how you would outside the Catalyst context. I'd recommend [Sub-Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sub-Exporter).

The `$ctx->model(...)` is meant for accessing a layer (`::Model::`) that is basically a "glue" between Catalyst and your business/model logic. If you don't need any glue (automatic configuration and component inflation for easier access is a common use-case), you can abstract it away as in every Perl application.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simply add that function and other useful ones as a Catalyst Plugin
and you can access it using the syntax `$c->sum_it_all()` (see sample plugin below)

========Example custom Plugin====

```
package Catalyst::Plugin::HelpUtils;
use strict;
use warnings;
our $VERSION = '1.0';

=head1 NAME

Catalyst::Plugin::HelpUtils


=head1 SYNOPSIS

    use Catalyst qw/
    Helputils
    /;

    To use any of the utilities in this plugin e.g:
    $c->sum_it_all()    


=cut

sub sum_it_all{
    my @items = @_;
    my $result = 0;
    foreach(@items) {
        $result += $_;
    }
    return $result;
}


1;
```

Comment: I don't recommend this. Often it ends up that you write a lot of code that is only usable in Catalyst and nowhere else. Even a "sum" function fits this. Because why should somebody write a sum function that is only usable in a Catalyst Controller? Only write a Catalyst plugin if it so specific that it don't make sense in any other context.

Answer (score 0):

I have set of functions in Utils.pm Helper package, through catalyst I want to access all the methods using $c->utils accessor.

For Eg:

```
package Utils

sub method1 {
}

sub method2 {
}
```

In catalyst, I would like to call method1 using `$c->utils->method1(<params>)` or `$c->utils->method2(<params>)`

Please let me know the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: hmm ... answer or question? If the latter, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)